# Keep Popup open and active as long as a TextBox has keyboard focus

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, popup

I have a Popup that I want to always be open and its content active when a TextBox has keyboard focus. I have attempted this with this code

```
public partial class MyPopup : Popup
{
    public MyPopup
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(
            typeof(UIElement),
            Keyboard.PreviewGotKeyboardFocusEvent,
            (KeyboardFocusChangedEventHandler)OnPreviewGotKeyboardFocus);
    }

    private void OnPreviewGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TextBox)
            this.IsOpen = true;
        else
            this.IsOpen = false;
    }
}
```

were I create the Popup in the constructor of App.

The problem with this code is that if the Popup is already open when ShowDialog is used the Popup is no longer active, even though it is still visually on top.

How do I get around this or get the required behavior in another way.

Comment: `C#` is not `C`, not even close. I assume that's a typo in the tag?

Comment: Yes, thanks, was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Found one solution where I check if the Window is opening by checking if it has loaded. If so I close the popup and reopen it again after the new Window has had its content rendered.

Not sure it's something I trust enough to use to use so a better solution would be welcome.

```
private void OnGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        if (sender is TextBox)
        {
            var _parentWindow = Window.GetWindow((UIElement)sender);
            if (!_parentWindow.IsLoaded)
            {
                this.IsOpen = false;
                _parentWindow.ContentRendered += (o, i) => this.IsOpen = true;
            }
            else
            {
                this.IsOpen = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.IsOpen = false;
        }
    }
```